# Packer Unable to validate the hcl2 template in jenkins job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, packer, hcl

I am working to build the packer pipeline I had created the json template which are working fine but as per the packer recommendation, I am working to upgrade it to the hcl2 template.
When i run the hcl2_upgrade command. I see a the json template is converted to the .pkr.hcl template but while running it. I have done some customization to template as per the recommded in packer documentation. While executing the pipeline through jenkins job , it gives me error.

template_pqr.json.pkr.hcl: Below is the starting line of my template over which it throws error

```
variable "ami_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "abc"
}
```

My jenkisn file is

```
stage('packer template validation') {
            steps{
                    sh label: 'Validate Template', script: "packer validate template_pqr.json.pkr.hcl"
           }
        }
        stage('AMI creation') {
            steps{
                    withAWS(credentials: 'credent') {
                        sh label: 'build template_pqr ', script: "packer build template_pqr.json.pkr.hcl"
                    }
            }
        }
       }
```

error:

```
packer validate template_pqr.json.pkr.hcl
Failed to parse template: Error parsing JSON: invalid character 'v' looking for beginning of value
At line 2, column 2 (offset 2):
    1: 
    2: v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is thrown when the `validate` command targets a HCL2 file in versions of Packer prior to version 1.6. That is the version of Packer which first introduced HCL2 support for the `validate` command (even though the `build` command was supported in 1.5). You need to update your Jenkins Pipeline agent to include an installed version of Packer that is at least 1.6.0. I would recommend the latest version of 1.6.x as 1.7 introduced plugin separation, which your templates and configs probably do not support.

[version 1.6.0 release notes: features](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-6)