# Data block not supported with packer version 1.6.1 in hcl2 templates

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, packer

I created a packer json template on my local system with packer 1.7.7 installed.

Then I upgraded to `hcl2` template. However, when I run the packer pipeline over the jenkins node having packer version 1.6.1. It throws this error:

```
Blocks of type "data" are not expected here.

Error: Unsupported block type
```

After researching, I realized that packer version 1.6.1 doesn't support data blocks in its templates, but it supports hcl2 templates.

Can anyone explain how I can replace the data block (ref template below) with something supported in packer version 1?

```
data "amazon-ami" "autogenerated_1"{
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
  filters = {
    root-device-type    = "ebs"
    virtualization-type = "hvm"
    name                = "**** Linux *"
  }
  most_recent = true
  region      = "${var.aws_region}" 
  owners      = ["${var.owner_id}"]
  secret_key  = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
}

when I am trying to consume this ami id in the source block It gives me error.
  ami_name                    = "${var.ami_name}"
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  force_deregister            = true
  iam_instance_profile        = "abc"
  instance_type               = "****"
  region                      = "${var.aws_region}"
  source_ami    = data.amazon-ami.autogenerated_1.id
  ssh_interface = "private_ip"
  ssh_username  = "user"
  subnet_id     = "subnet-********"
  vpc_id        = "vpc-***********"
}
```

Comment: @Marcin can you please suggest

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you should upgrade your packer?

Answer (score 0):

> The packer pipeline over the jenkins node having packer version 1.6.1.

Its not supported in such an **old version**. From [docs](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/hcl_templates/datasources):

> Note: Data Sources is a feature included in **Packer 1.7** and later

Comment: is there a workaround for this @Marcin

Comment: How shud i pass the source image filter in my hcl2 template without data block

Comment: @knowledge20 Sadly, I don't know. It would be best if you used current version of packer, rather then some old version.